# How is 潔{いさぎよ}い related to 清{きよ}い?

Tags: etymology

How is 潔{いさぎよ}い related to 清{きよ}い?

First, I'd like to point out this question: [[潔]{いさぎよ}い　meaning](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/%E6%BD%94%E3%81%84%E3%81%95%E3%81%8E%E3%82%88%E3%81%84%E3%80%80meaning)

Second, I've found a possible [etymology for 潔{いさぎよ}い on gogen-allguide](http://gogen-allguide.com/i/isagiyoi.html).

Gogen-allguide seems to say that いさぎよい probably comes from 甚{いた} + 清{きよし}, with いた expressing "to a great extent".  Assuming I understood right, I don't quite see how this leads to the modern meaning(s) discussed in the other question.

I've also seen the word きよい written as 潔{きよ}い.  This has me puzzled, too, because I'm not sure if it's supposed to express anything besides 清い.  (My character dictionary doesn't list any such nuance, if so.)  Is this a hint to the connection between these words, or a red herring?

Comment: I learned them as "immaculate" (潔い) and "clean" (清い), but I don't know if the nuances translate over...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

gogen-allguide says that for the 'いさ’ part of いさぎよい, there are suggested origins of いた (甚) or 勇{いさ}む・勇{いさ}.  The exact origin appears unclear.

At any rate, it suggests that the modern meanings to do with character reflect the meaning of 勇, not 甚.

[This blog](http://blog.livedoor.jp/kannon_bosatsu/archives/50111115.html) has it as 勇・清い as well, and defines it as 勇ましく清らかな 状態{じょうたい}を保{たも}つ決意{けつい}を表{あらわ}す. [This](http://www.bl.mmtr.or.jp/~isamutg/komimi/24.htm) gives the same origin, although it's more complaining about people mistaking it as being いさぎ・よい and saying things like いさぎがよい・いさぎがわるい.

Comment: “it suggests that the modern meanings to do with character reflect the meaning of 勇, not 甚”: I think that something is wrong with this sentence.  Maybe you meant to delete “to do with character”?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, I *think* nkjt means "to with *a person's* character".  Any other meaning just seems confusing to me.